# Dragging element across DIVs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

What I'd like to do is drag an element created in a visualsearch.js (documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/‎) search box (class="search_facet not_editing not_selected" [or the last element can be "is_selected"]) and drop it into a separate box.  I'm currently facing two issues:

1. With my current code, I can move my elements and/or helpers, but only within the search box.
2. I can only make these elements draggable if I do something else, i.e., I'd like it to become draggable when I click on any '.search_facet' class item, but if I use that as my event, all dragging code becomes unresponsive.

**JS**

```
//Creates object on which to apply event [See issue #2]
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( init );
    function init() {
        $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
    }
});
//Applies draggability to '.search_facet'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#makeMeDraggable').click(function(){
        $('.search_facet').draggable({
            cursor: 'move',
            helper: 'clone',
            //appendTo: '.droppable', /*If uncommented, element can leave the search box, but loses entire styling and form */
            zIndex: 99999
        });
    });
});
//Creates droppable target
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        drop: 'handleDrop',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        zIndex: 1
    });
    //Should allow for dragging between DIVs?
    function handleDrop(event,ui) {
        var targetDIV = document.getElementById('targetDIV');
        var dropTarget = $(this);
        ui.draggable.insertBefore(dropTarget);
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span>
    <div id="search_box_container"></div> //These two elements implement visualsearch
    <div id="search_jquery">&nbsp;</div> //These two elements implement visualsearch
    <div id="makeMeDraggable"></div> //Creates a box to click that allows draggability
    <div class="droppable"></div> //Creates a droppable target
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for jQuery.sortable() with connectWith to connect the elements you want to drag between.

See: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: I definitely think using the .sortable() function will be better than using .draggable(), but I'm still not able to move elements from one div to another.  I can still use appendTo to at least get outside the container's boundaries, but it loses styling, and won't stop in the other drop target.